# Python "freeze" does not include namespace

Tags: python, build, setuptools, setup.py

This is the script called `sharkfest.py`:

```
import os, sys

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(sys.modules[__name__])
```

When I run the script, it displays the module name as `sharkfest.py`

```sh
Python38-32\python.exe sharkfest.py 
<module '__main__' from 'sharkfest.py'>
```

but when I freeze it and run it as an executable the module name is `built-in`

This is the `setup.py` file:

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
options = {"packages":["errno","psycopg2","requests","simplecrypt"]}
setup(name = "Shark" ,
    version = "0.1" ,
    description = "" ,
    options= {"build_exe": options},
    executables = [Executable("sharkfest.py")])
```

Here is the command used to freeze:

```sh
c:\Python38-32\python.exe setup.py build
```

and here is the output when running the executable `sharkfest.exe`:

```sh
module '__main__' (built-in)
```

My question is, how can I have the module to be `sharkfest.py` and not
`built-in`. is there any parameter or option that needs to be added
to the setup.py file?